# limitar la edicion de las filas en un gridview en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, gridview

tengo el siguiente `**GridView**`

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="idActividad" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource66" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
     <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idActividad" HeaderText="id Actividad" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"  SortExpression="idActividad" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" SortExpression="descripcion" ReadOnly="True"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cantidad" HeaderText="Cantidad" 
            SortExpression="cantidad"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fecTerminacion" HeaderText="Fecha Terminación Formato (Mes-Dia-Año)" 
            SortExpression="fecTerminacion" DataFormatString="{0:M-dd-yyyy}" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true"
            HtmlEncode="False" HtmlEncodeFormatString="False"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nomPrestador" HeaderText="Prestador" 
            SortExpression="nomPrestador" ReadOnly="True"/>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="blnCumplio" HeaderText="Cumplio Plan" 
            SortExpression="blnCumplio" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

tengo habilitada la opción de actualizar un los campos y me gustaría saber como hacer validaciones para actualizar el campo de fecha porque permite agregar cualquier cosa y no puede hacer después la actualización.

Comment: Hola, yo ese tipo de validaciones las hago doble, por una parte en el cliente con jquery por ejemplo, añadiendo una clase css o un id para saber que tengo que validar, y luego en la parte de servidor antes de hacer el update en la base de datos, por supuesto tambien compruebo todos los tipos de campos, algo así podría valerte?

Comment: Si claro, lo que sea pero que admita unicamente el formato de fecha